# How should I implement interface composition?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, composition

I have this situation:

```
public interface IHasValue<T>
    {
        T Value { get; set; }
    }

public interface IClickable
    {
        void SubscribeOnClick(EventHandler click);
    }

public interface ILoginView : IView
    {
        IHasValue<string> Username { get; }
        IHasValue<string> Password { get; }
        IClickable Login { get; }
        IClickable Cancel { get; }
    }

public partial class LoginVIew : Form, ILoginView
    {
        public LoginVIew()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region ILoginView Members

        public IHasValue<string> Username
        {
            get { ?? }
        }

        public IHasValue<string> Password
        {
            get { ?? }
        }

        public IClickable Login
        {
            get { ?? }
        }

        public IClickable Cancel
        {
            get { ?? }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

How should I implement this? I have no idea.

Comment: With code? Seriously, I have no idea either.  Can you be specific?

Comment: Well, I was hoping if there is some way to create internal class objects which implement those interfaces. Like to provide some methods in this get section which would implement specific interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you'll need to implement `IHasValue<T>` and `IClickable` in order to be able to create an implementation of `ILoginView` (because you need to be able to create instances of object implementing those interfaces in the `ILoginView` members.

```
 public class StringValue : IHasValue<string>
 {
     public string Value { get; set; }
 }

 public interface LoginClickable : IClickable
 {
     public void SubscribeOnClick(EventHandler click)
     {
          // do something to login
     }
 } 

 public interface CancelClickable : IClickable
 {
     public void SubscribeOnClick(EventHandler click)
     {
          // do something to cancel
     }
 }
```

...

```
    public IHasValue<string> Username
    {
        get { return new StringValue { Value = "Username" }; }
    }

    public IHasValue<string> Password
    {
         get { return new StringValue { Value = "Password" }; }
    }

    public IClickable Login
    {
        get { return new LoginClickable(); }
    }

    public IClickable Cancel
    {
        get { return new CancelClickable(); }
    }
```

Comment: Is the closed `StringValue` required? Can it not be done with `class Value<T> : IHasValue<T>`?

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion. It depends on the OP's requirements. Maybe there will be more logic in there.

Comment: There is no any other, more elegant way to do that in property?

Comment: Well, in order to implement an interface you will need a class.

Comment: Ah, yes. Your right. I just got a little bit confused. I just need to use my regular control which will implement those interfaces and provide wanted methods.

Comment: @Vajda: note that you don't necessarily need to expose the implementation types; you can declare them as private nested types, if the outside world should have no knowledge of the implementation details.